# UITableView as subview in AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

After surprisingly the world didn't end today I continue coding,

I made UITableViewController, it works very good when using segue, but I want to make this controller subview in AppDelegete (to make side menu like facebook).

So I my AppDelegate (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) I added this:

```
UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

SideMenuViewController * rm = (SideMenuViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RightMenu"];

[self.window addSubview:rm.tableView];
```

it adds the table and the table renders correctly,
**until** I click on some cell or try to scroll,
and suddenly everything in this table disappears,
I see compltely empty table, no section and no cells.

What can I do?
It may be some delegate issues because it's instantiated in the AppDelegate?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I agree that it's likely a delegate issue, but you didn't supply any of that code. I would not do what you are doing in the AppDelegate. I think a re-visit of your design (technical) is in order.

Comment: Why do you want to programatically set root/initial controller? There is a checkbox for that in IB whe editing Storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

You must set a `rootViewControlle`r property of the `window`. May be this will help..any way insert this code between adding the table as subview and controller instantiation:

```
self.window.rootViewController = rm;
```

Comment: +1. Setting `rootViewController` is the only way of displaying something in iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience whatsoever with storyboards, so this is a wild guess: Is the `SideMenuViewController` instance being deallocated after it is used to populate the initial table view? The `UIStoryboard` object sure seems to be non-retained, but I am not sure about the controller returned by `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`.